# Re-learning mathematics from scratch without khan

Tags: logic, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, foundations

I apologize for asking this question since it has likely been asked around 100 times before, but I haven't found anything that quite suits me.

First, I wanted to revisit mathematics from the ground up (completely) because my mathematics education has been extremely hollow. I can solve problems but I take a long time because my foundations are essentially a fraction of what they should be. So I can work through for example baby Rudin (enough mathematical maturity) but I would take a lot longer than I should on parts because I don't know some of the elementary results readily, therefore I want to patch this up.
I kind of don't want to feel like I am bringing a exhausting miracle onto the paper that somehow is correct with the fraction of what I do know every time.

There are certain kinds of book styles I prefer which others tend to find very terse. In general there are 3 categories to these :

1. Theorem-Proof books : State theorem, show proof.
2. Problem books : Problems and **Correct Solutions**
3. Encyclopedia/Reference/Axiom style books: What someone would call a reference of...

My personal interests are in Logic,Combinatorics, Topology,Geometry,Computation,Statistics,Probability,Analysis and Algebra.

I want to at least get a overly solid foundation ready to where it is appropriate to delve fully into any of the above areas.

The reason I don't want to use Khan (#2) for the above is because I prefer a more detailed book-based approach, I can't personally stand using videos.

Is there a better suited: book guide, series or sets of books for me?

Comment: "My personal interests are in Logic,Combinatorics, Topology,Geometry,Computation,Statistics,Probability,Analysis and Algebra." You've basically listed every field of Math, so it's going to be hard for anyone to answer because you've essentially asked for prescribed types of resources for most every mathematical field.

Comment: Ironically I did this off the top of my head earnestly thinking about my interests...
I suppose my question was more in reference to a foundation than to my interests particularly~enough to start tackling all of these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach makes sense, especially when so many people suffer from the same problem now - *fragmental mathematical knowledge*. You might get a lot of book recommendations, and you'll need to process a lot of information - good luck!

Fortunately, such lists of books already exist - for example, [this one](https://mathblog.com/mathematics-books) looks comprehensive and sturdy.

Comment: Thank you, I have bookmarked that link. That is indeed helpful particularly for what I wanted but the linear algebra section seems a little less complete than the others or is axler alone comparable to Linear Algebra as is Spivak and Apostol  to Calculus (I,II,III)?

Comment: @JohnSchneider - you are probably right about the Linear Algebra section - it looks weak. Take a look at this book:  https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Linear-Algebra-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486660826 - it's very well written. Strang book is also classic